# How to use ConvertToWritableTypes in scala spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I was looking at [BasicSaveSequenceFile](https://github.com/holdenk/learning-spark-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/com/oreilly/learningsparkexamples/java/BasicSaveSequenceFile.java) and tried to follow this in `scala`

So I had:

```
val input = Seq(("coffee", 1), ("coffee", 2), ("pandas", 3))
val inputRDD = sc.parallelize(input) // no parallelizePairs
```

but then when I try:

```
val outputRDD = inputRDD.map(new ConvertToWritableTypes()) // I have no mapToPair how to write that instead?
```

How to use ConvertToWritableTypes in scala spark?

right now I get:

```
Error:(29, 38) type mismatch;
 found   : SparkExampleWriteSeqLZO.ConvertToWritableTypes
 required: ((String, Int)) => ?
        val outputRDD = inputRDD.map(new ConvertToWritableTypes())
                                     ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you're looking at the Java version, you really should be looking at the [Scala version](https://github.com/holdenk/learning-spark-examples/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/oreilly/learningsparkexamples/scala/BasicSaveSequenceFile.scala) as the API's are fairly different. From the example give, you don't need `mapToPair`, you can just use a normal `map` without the static class:

```
  import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable
  import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text

  val input = Seq(("coffee", 1), ("coffee", 2), ("pandas", 3))
  val inputRDD = sc.parallelize(input)

  val outputRDD = inputRDD.map(record => (new Text(record._1), new IntWritable(record._2)))
```

You really don't need to do this though, as the Scala example I linked to shows you:

```
  val data = sc.parallelize(List(("Holden", 3), ("Kay", 6), ("Snail", 2)))
  data.saveAsSequenceFile(outputFile)
```